# hibernate how to select the many-side from an one-to-many relation

Tags: java, hibernate

everyone. I'm brand new using Hibernate.

So here I face a question, I have an entity like below:

```
<class name="cn.edu.scau.librarica.dao.MessageSession" table="msg_session">
    <id name="msid" type="long" unsaved-value="null">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <list name="msgs" cascade="all">
        <key column="msid" 
            update="false" unique="true" not-null="true"/>
        <list-index column="list_index"/>
        <one-to-many class="Message" />
    </list>
</class>
```

And now what I want to achieve is:

```
    select Message m where msid=# and m.t<## and m.t>###
```

How can I represent it with Criteria?
Thank you for your attentions and advices, in advance.

---

**UPDATE**
As one of the answer guide, I have got the point that composite-element is not queryable, so I made a both-sid one-to-many map(changed are above)
And now I can query but now I found another problem:
**How can I mapped the composite-id with foreign-key**
`Message` are map like this:

```
<class name="Message">
    <composite-id>
         <generator class="foreign">
             <!-- What here??? -->
         </generator>
    </composite-id>
</class>
```

As instructed, one-to-many may use `set` rather than `list`, so I can hardly find sample meets my need(due to Message should be ordered).
Any advice? I am still searching for that.
Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to map Message class similar like how you mapped MessageSession and write criteria query as explained on hibernate's manual

Comment: You need to say <generator class="assigned">  and leave it empty. That means hibernate will not automatically generate ids when you create new instances of message - you will have to do it in your program.

Comment: <generator class="foreign"/> doesn't mean what you think it means :-).  Take my earlier advise - spend some time reading up about hibernate.

Comment: @gkamal Thanks, I get it. Currently I use a generated id (which is meaningless for my business). What the true problem is, hibernate does not allow me to make the key `insert="false" update="false"`, so that I can't map the properties to the same db column. Whatever, and fortunately, my require is fulfilled. Later I will summary my solution and end this question(as "how to match key properties to same column" is another topic). I will keep on searching to seek the best, and thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly select the Message as it is a component and not an entity.  Components don't have an independent life cycle.  They cannot be queried, created or deleted on their own, they always have to be accessed via the entity in which they are embedded (MessageSession in your case).

To make it into an Entity the table should have it's own primary key.  In your case that doesn't seem to be so.  You will need to change the schema so that the table corresponding to Message has a primary key and change the mapping to use one-to-many instead of composite-element.

If you can't do that you will have to query the MessageSession and get message out of it.

P.S: Hibernate is quite complex, I haven't see too many people being able to just pick it up along the way just trying things out. You are more likely to succeed if you spend some time studying the underlying concepts (which are more important than just mapping & querying).

Comment: Thanks and I see that only one-to-many mapping is the right way, but now I meet with a new problem, can you help? :3

Answer (score 0):

here is the author of question.

After several days of research, I found the way to satisfied my require somehow.

**Maping `Message`**

```
<class name="cn.edu.scau.librarica.dao.Message" table="message">
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="ms" class="cn.edu.scau.librarica.dao.MessageSession" 
     column="msid" not-null="true" insert="false" update="false" />
    <property name="s" type="long" />
    <property name="t" type="timestamp" />
    <property name="m" type="string" />
</class>
```

**Mapping `MessageSession`**

```
<class name="cn.edu.scau.librarica.dao.MessageSession" table="msg_session">
    <id name="msid" type="long" unsaved-value="null">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <property name="latest" type="timestamp" />

    <list name="msgs" table="msg_session_msgs" cascade="all">
        <key column="msid" 
            update="false" not-null="true"/>
        <list-index column="list_index"/>
        <one-to-many class="cn.edu.scau.librarica.dao.Message" />
    </list>
</class>
```

Among them, the unimportant are neglected.

Things go quite well while I can find the "one" with restrictions of "many" or inversely. just like this:

```
        DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Message.class)
            .createCriteria("ms")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("msid", msid));

        if (after != null)
            dc.add(Restrictions.gt("t", after));

        if (before != null)
            dc.add(Restrictions.lt("t", before));
```

...can search out `Message` during the specified period from specified `MessageSession`.

So the trick is **objects can't be returned by Criteria unless match them as entity.**

On the underlaying database, it will be a little redundant, since `Message` can be uniquely identified by `(msid,list_index)`, so I am finding a way to match <-this as the primary key for `Message`.